# Is there a way to take a user input in Grafana Dashboard?

Tags: user-interface, user-input, grafana

I am currently working on Time Series Data and displaying it using Grafana in form of graphs. I have a use case where when the values goes down from a particular level then a question should be asked from user and its response should be saved in datasource like in case Its Influxdb .

To give an example , if the value of temperature drops to 10 F  then some question should be fired to user and asked is this normal ? and its response yes or no should be added back to influx.

Is there a way in which I can achieve this using Grafana ?